# Problem with special characters

Tags: android, sqlite, character

How can I change the font on android to allow to show special characters like "'" or "à"?
Actually the strings that contains these characters are stored in the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Android SQLite uses UTF-8. 
I had this problem because when I populated the database on the first launch I used a txt file with another charset.

Comment: This ans doesn't help much, can you please explain little broadly ?

Comment: I was populating my database using a text file with an encode different from UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

When you load the text into your `TextView`, will this work for you?

```
textView.setText(new String(textFromDatabase, "UTF-8"));
```

This uses the String constructor to set the charset name. You can change "UTF-8" to a different [Character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) -- Also, look at the javadoc for [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

> `String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)` - 
>   Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified charset.

Comment: Despite working perfectly, and being a valid alternative, I would advice anyone to avoid setting encoding on-the-fly, before displaying text. Generally speaking, one wouldn't want to mix and remember different encodings when coding (encoding hell), since that (easily) brings all the potential debug issues. My choice would be to do the encoding at read-time, store in UTF-8 (for all the well known reasons, or at least the encoding you use by default) and check/forget about the encoding from that on. The only case I wouldn't is if I'm unable/forbidden to change the content.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I just threw this out as an option. I can't count the number of times I have come across a one-off useful solution on StackOverflow... something I wasn't able to find elsewhere.

Comment: Changing the charset doesn't work. Probabily the problem is in the cursor.

Comment: @Marco Cali I don't have any other thoughts at the moment, but if you figure it out, please post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Droid font supports the "'", "à" and many others characters. I use them all the time (pt language).

Actually, I'm quite sure they support all the Basic Latin, Latin 1 supplement and the first extended latin range. They also support many others like hebrew etc., although I'm not sure if that changed between SDK versions.

You can also download the Unicode Map app in the Market to check which characters are available in your particular device. I also store unicode text in sqlite all the time, and still I don't have any problems.

One thing to consider: check that the encoding you are setting match the encoding of your source. It may be a text or a URL... an example:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), MY_ENCODING));
```

Are you sure it's not a problem somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `''` instead of `'` to store it into Sqlite database.
For example if you want to store `5 o'clock` into database then you have to write this as `5 O''clock`. Take a look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14), for more information about it.

Comment: I never have problems storing single quotes in sqlite from Android. Also, he says he gets problems not only on single quotes, but also on many other "special" (i.e., besides the Basic Latin range from Unicode) characters as well.