# How to display proper Latin characters in android textview?

Tags: android, sqlite, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display Latin words in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452621/how-can-i-display-latin-words-in-android)

I have to fetch text from an Sqlite database  and every special Latin character (i.e. à, ò, ù, è...) was displayed with black squares with a "?" inside.

How can i display this correctly?

i Used DatabaseHelper in below:

```
public class VocabTesterDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.VoacabTester/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "vocabdb.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase vocabDatabase;

    private final Context vocabContext;

    public VocabTesterDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
        this.vocabContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        try {

            InputStream myInput = vocabContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("data", e.toString().concat("sql"));
        }
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        vocabDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    public Cursor getFoundationTierQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM FoundationTierVocabularyQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    };

    public Cursor getHigherTierQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM HigherTierQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getEasyFirstConjugationVerbs() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM VerbQuestions1stConjugation ORDER BY Random()",
                null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getEasySecondConjugationVerbs() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM VerbQuestions2ndConjugation ORDER BY Random()",
                null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getEasyThirdConjugationVerbs() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM VerbQuestions3rdConjugation ORDER BY Random()",
                null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getEasyFourthConjugationVerbs() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM VerbQuestions4thConjugation ORDER BY Random()",
                null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getEasyMixConjugationVerbs() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM VerbQuestionsallConjugation ORDER BY Random()",
                null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getEasyIrregularConjugationVerbs() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM IrregularVerbsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getFirstDeclensionNounsQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM FirstDeclensionNounsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getSecondDeclensionNounsQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM SecondDeclensionNounsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getThirdDeclensionNounsQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM ThirdDeclensionNounsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getFourthDeclensionNounsQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM FourthDeclensionNounsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getFifthDeclensionNounsQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM FifthDeclensionNounsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getNounsAllDeclensionNounsQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM NounsDeclensionNounsQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getis_ea_idQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IsEaIdQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor gethic_haec_hocQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM HicHaecHocQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getille_illa_illudQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IlleIllaIlludQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getqui_quae_quodQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM QuiQuaeQuodQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getIdem_eadem_idemQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IdemEademIdemQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getipse_ipsa_ipsumQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IpseIpsaIpsumQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getalius_alia_aliudQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM AliusAliaAliudQuestions ORDER BY Random()",
                        null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAdjectiveQuestions() {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM AdjectivesQuestions ORDER BY Random()", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerFirstDeclensionNounsQuestion(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM FirstDeclensionNounsQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getSAnswerecondDeclensionNounsQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM SecondDeclensionNounsQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerThirdDeclensionNounsQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM ThirdDeclensionNounsQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerFourthDeclensionNounsQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM FourthDeclensionNounsQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerFifthDeclensionNounsQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM FifthDeclensionNounsQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerNounsAllDeclensionNounsQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM NounsDeclensionNounsQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnsweris_ea_idQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IsEaIdQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerhic_haec_hocQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM HicHaecHocQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerille_illa_illudQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IlleIllaIlludQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerqui_quae_quodQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM QuiQuaeQuodQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerIdem_eadem_idemQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IdemEademIdemQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnsweripse_ipsa_ipsumQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM IpseIpsaIpsumQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnsweralius_alia_aliudQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;
        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM AliusAliaAliudQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    public Cursor getAnswerAdjectiveQuestions(String question) {
        Cursor cur;

        cur = vocabDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM AdjectivesQuestions WHERE Question LIKE '"
                        + question + "'", null);

        cur.moveToFirst();
        vocabDatabase.close();
        return cur;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (vocabDatabase != null)
            vocabDatabase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

I used Activity class in below:

```
public class VocabTesterAdjectiveActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView question;
    private TextView stats;
    private Button skipButton;
    private Button finishButton;

    final VocabTesterDatabaseHelper dbObj = new VocabTesterDatabaseHelper(this);

    Cursor questionCursor;
    Cursor answerCursor;
    Button userAnserButtoon;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    String adjectiveNumber;
    String adjectiveCase;
    String adjectiveGender;

    int totalNumberOfQuestions = 0;
    int totalRightQuestions = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adjective_test);

        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionView);
        stats = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalView);

        skipButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipButton);
        finishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
        userAnserButtoon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage("No More Questions");
        alertDialog.setTitle("Finish");

        skipButton.setOnClickListener(skipClickListener);
        finishButton.setOnClickListener(finishClickListener);
        userAnserButtoon.setOnClickListener(answerClickListener);

        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        getAllQuestions();
        displayTestQuestion();

    }

    private void displayTestQuestion() {
        resetEverything();
        stats.setText(Integer.toString(totalRightQuestions) + "/"
                + Integer.toString(totalNumberOfQuestions));

        String questionText = questionCursor.getString(0);

        question.setText(questionText);
        //question.setText(Html.fromHtml(questionText));
        adjectiveNumber = questionCursor.getString(1);
        adjectiveCase = questionCursor.getString(3);
        adjectiveGender = questionCursor.getString(2);
    }

    private void resetEverything() {

        RadioGroup adjectiveNumberList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adjectiveNumberList);
        adjectiveNumberList.clearCheck();

        RadioGroup adjectiveCaseList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adjectiveCaseList);
        adjectiveCaseList.clearCheck();

        RadioGroup adjectiveGenderList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adjectiveGenderList);
        adjectiveGenderList.clearCheck();

        userAnserButtoon.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY,
                Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    private void getAllQuestions() {
        try {
            dbObj.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dbObj.openDataBase();
        questionCursor = dbObj.getAdjectiveQuestions();
    }

    private OnClickListener finishClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(VocabTesterAdjectiveActivity.this,
                    VocabTesterHomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener skipClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!questionCursor.isLast()) {
                questionCursor.moveToNext();
                totalNumberOfQuestions++;
                displayTestQuestion();
            } else {
                alertDialog.setMessage("No More Questions");
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener answerClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String useSelectedNumber = "";
            String useSelectedCase = "";
            String useSelectedGender = "";

            RadioGroup adjectiveNumberList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adjectiveNumberList);
            int count = adjectiveNumberList.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View radio = adjectiveNumberList.getChildAt(i);
                if (radio instanceof RadioButton) {
                    if (((RadioButton) radio).isChecked()) {
                        useSelectedNumber = ((String) ((RadioButton) radio)
                                .getText()).toLowerCase();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            RadioGroup adjectiveCaseList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adjectiveCaseList);
            count = adjectiveCaseList.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View radio = adjectiveCaseList.getChildAt(i);
                if (radio instanceof RadioButton) {
                    if (((RadioButton) radio).isChecked()) {
                        useSelectedCase = ((String) ((RadioButton) radio)
                                .getText()).toLowerCase();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            RadioGroup adjectiveGenderList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adjectiveGenderList);
            count = adjectiveGenderList.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View radio = adjectiveGenderList.getChildAt(i);
                if (radio instanceof RadioButton) {
                    if (((RadioButton) radio).isChecked()) {
                        useSelectedGender = ((String) ((RadioButton) radio)
                                .getText()).toLowerCase();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            dbObj.openDataBase();
            answerCursor = dbObj.getAnswerAdjectiveQuestions(questionCursor
                    .getString(0));
            boolean isCorrect = false;

            while (!answerCursor.isLast()) {
                if (useSelectedNumber.equals(answerCursor.getString(1))
                        && useSelectedGender.equals(answerCursor.getString(2))
                        && useSelectedCase.equals(answerCursor.getString(3))) {
                    isCorrect = true;
                    break;
                }
                answerCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            if (useSelectedNumber.equals(answerCursor.getString(1))
                    && useSelectedGender.equals(answerCursor.getString(2))
                    && useSelectedCase.equals(answerCursor.getString(3))) {
                isCorrect = true;
            }
            if (isCorrect) {
                userAnserButtoon.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN,
                        Mode.MULTIPLY);
                totalRightQuestions++;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (!questionCursor.isLast()) {
                            questionCursor.moveToNext();
                            totalNumberOfQuestions++;
                            displayTestQuestion();
                        } else {
                            alertDialog.setMessage("No More Questions");
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);

            } else {
                userAnserButtoon.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED,
                        Mode.MULTIPLY);
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        totalNumberOfQuestions++;
                        displayTestQuestion();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Check the encoding of whatever's displaying the text

Comment: i set the textview in "bonō" and display in my emulator "bon?".

Comment: @crickpatel0024, “ō” is not a Latin-1 character. And this seems to be a duplicate of your question, where you have accepted an answer.

Comment: but i couldn't proper solution of my question.please help me!!!

Comment: then you shouldnt have accepted an answer that didnt work!

Comment: i can try this answer but any changes my textview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your file encoding format:

`System.setProperty("file.encoding","Latin-1");`

Comment: not working this